# Spring Security: conditional logic based on roles

Tags: spring-security

I'm using the Spring security tags to determine if people are authenticated or have roles etc. For example

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('MANAGER')">
```

I'm struggling to see how to do conditional logic with this though. I want to say something like this (I made the last tags up):

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('MANAGER')">
    Hello Mr Manager
</sec:authorize>
<sec:otherwise>
    Hello Mr Non-Manager
</sec:otherwise>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you already solved this, but to finish the question:

Look at documentation at: [Spring Security TagLib](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html)

And you can use this snippet:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<sec:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_USER">
    Hello Mr. Anonymous
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_USER" ifNotGranted="ROLE_MANAGER">
    Hello Mr. User
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_MANAGER">
    Hello Mr. Manager
</sec:authorize>
```